# Rails MVC Architecture - View with multiple controller sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, architecture, controller

I have a page in my rails application that is the show action for one controller, but it includes a form that submits to create for another. This is fine for simply submitting a create form to the second controller, but because the form is contained in the show action of an alternate controller, I can't easily show validation errors on the form. Here's a basic idea of the structure:

```ruby
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @vendor = […]
  end
end
```

```erb
<!-- vendors_controller/show -->
<h1><%= @vendor.name %></h1>

<%= form_with model: Order, local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :vendor_id, value: @vendor.id %>

  […]
<% end %>
```

```ruby
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = […]
    if @order.save
      […]
    else
      render 'new' # Not where user came from, actually want to go to vendors_controller/show
    end
  end
end
```

The only way I have found to handle creating orders within the context of "new" being the `vendors_controller/show` is to move `OrdersController#create` to a custom `create_order` method inside `VendorsController`, but this moves core REST logic for a model to a different controller, which feels like a major code smell. Coming from a mobile engineering background, we can split our screens into multiple sub-views with independent controllers for distinct elements, but of course this isn't really feasible on web since a single controller handles the incoming request and it's response.

What would be the correct way to structure this behavior so that I can retain most of the REST functionality for the `OrdersController` while also "embedding" the new action into a view owned by another controller? I want to keep the `Order` related logic inside `OrdersController`, but redirecting back to `VendorsController#show` breaks errors from validation and in the future I might also want a `OrdersController#new` route with identical logic but separate from `VendorsController`.

Comment: Conceptually you can actually split the view into different "controllers" but on the web thats done with JavaScript and XHR requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually a fairly common scenario that you don't have a separate `new` action for a resource. And you're kind of reasoning about it wrong in Rails terms as its really just about what view you're rendering and sending back in response to the request.

You can handle invalid form submissions here either by rendering the new view (which might not be the UX you're looking for) or by using AJAX to submit the form and replace the elements in place:

```
// app/views/orders/new.js.erb
document.querySelector("#order_form")
        .innerHTML("<%= j(render(partial: 'form', locals: { order: @order })) %>");
```

```
# app/views/orders/_form.html.erb
# removed "local: true" so thats its sent as a XHR request
<%= form_with model: order, html: { id: "order_form" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :vendor_id %> # smelly AF - use a nested route instead
<% end %>
```

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = […]
    if @order.save
      […]
    else
      respond_to do |f|
        f.js { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't want to go down the [Server Side Concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns) (aka js.erb spagetti) route you could do a JSON response and handle rendering the errors on the client side.

While it is possible to render the `vendors/show.html.erb` view instead from your `OrdersController#create` method instead if validation fails its a downright unsexy proposition as it makes that controller responsible for rendering a completely different resource.

While this isn't really an issue in this simple example if you add features to the "vendors/show" view you would have to duplicate the logic of setting up the data you're passing to the view in two places.

Even if you do cut the potential code duplication issues by using horizontal inheritance (concerns) you're still trampling on the Single Responibility Principle.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # POST /vendors/:vendor_id/orders
  def create
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    @order = […]
    if @order.save
      […]
    else
      render "vendors/show"
    end
  end
end
```

Having your VendorsController handle creating orders is even worse and should not even be considered.

Comment: There are a few additional issues here - you're using `model: Order` and passing the class instead of an instance of Order. Bad idea as you have to pass all the user input through on the side. You're also using a hidden input where you should be using a nested route. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Ajax, so concerns is a good compromise. I was hoping for a traditionally rendered HTML method, but it looks like concerns are the correct way of handling this sort of issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I would really call it the correct way.

Comment: "Least smelly" then. This method does requiring additional view files, but separation of concerns is much better this way.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though is that this will reload the page and the scroll to the top which can be a more "janky" user experience then ajax.

Comment: Good to note. Shouldn't be an issue on this page, especially since the plan was to reload the page anyway via redirects, but Ajax may be an option for UI overhaul down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

[There's a railscasts episode on this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) that explains how to do nested forms while preserving RESTfulness

You would more or less do something like:

```
<!-- vendors_controller/show -->

<h1><%= @vendor.name %></h1>

<%= fields_for :orders do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'order_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

and then put the order form fields in a new partial:

```
<!-- app/views/vendors/_order_fields.html.erb -->

<%= f.hidden_field :vendor_id, value: @vendor.id %>

<!-- and the rest of the order fields, too... -->
```

And don't forget to include a line like `@vendor.orders.build` in you vendor#show controller logic

Comment: While I do appreachiate that you made the effort to write and answer nested attributes is not really applicable here. This is not really the case where you need to create nested resources in a single form submission - rather its a rather common scenario where you have a form that does not live on a separate `/new` route but is embedded in the view of another resource.

Comment: I will take a deeper look at the railscast, but as per max's comment, it looks like this may not quite solve my issue. I already use partials for some forms, it's more the controller logic that I am worried about: how to avoid duplicating the logic that belongs in `OrdersController` in `VendorsController` while keeping the `new` view (or at least, one of several `new` views) inside a view managed by `VendorsController`.

Comment: Yeah it definitely won't solve anything here. Nested attributes would be suitable if you wanted to create a vendor and orders in a single form submission. You also want to take into account that RailsCasts has been defunct for almost 10 years and while they where excellent back then they are badly dated today.